Luck Boost for a item drop system in js
I have an item dropping system but i want to be able to give the player more luck
const blocks = [
    {
        name: "Iron",
        ratio: 1 / 2,
    },
    {
        name: "Gold nugget",
        ratio: 1 / 4,
    },
    {
        name: "Green Amulet",

        ratio: 1 / 10,
    },
    {
        name: "Red Gem",
        ratio: 1 / 20,
    },
    {
        name: "Diamond",

        ratio: 1 / 100,
    }
]


const totalRatio = blocks.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.ratio, 0);

function rollItem(luckIncreasePercentage = 0) {


    const luckboost = (1000 * Math.random());


    let roll = Math.random();


    let cumulativeChance = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        cumulativeChance += blocks[i].ratio / totalRatio;
        if (roll <= cumulativeChance) {
            return blocks[i];
        }
    }
}

I want to be able to add a luckboost percent for example 10% more lucky of some sort
i already did something that would do more Math.randoms and take the highest one but i am not satisfied with the solution because if you have a crazy amount of luck it starts to lag out

You can raise the roll to a power that is less than 1. The lower the power, the more roll will tend towards 1 (the "boost").
So for instance you could do this:
let roll = Math.random() ** ((100 - luckIncreasePercentage) / 100);

So if luckIncreasePercentage is 0 (which means there's no boost), this reduces to just Math.random() ** 1, i.e. Math.random(). On the other extreme, if luckIncreasePercentage is 100 (the maximum boost), roll will be 1, no matter what Math.random() was, since it was raised to the power 0.
